# Print a single report after all suites is executed

Tags: java, selenium, testng

My problem is as follows:

I use testng for running tests. I have several test suites(Suite1.xml, Suite2.xml and Suite3.xml), which are combined in one suite (MasterSuite.xml).
Once the mastersuite is executed I need a report with passed , failed and skipped cases.

i have used itestresult in @BeforeMethod

```
public void writeResult(ITestResult result) {

    try {
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
            passedcount++;

        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            failedcount++;

            } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
            skippedcount++;
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

unable to get a single result like this after all suites (suite1 ,suite2 ,suite3) has run ( suite 1 , suite 2 , suite 3 )
Passed count is 7
Failed count is  1
Skipped count is 4

Comment: actually, this is an assignment, not a problem or an issue. what is your actual question?

Comment: I am unable to print a single result after all suites is executed.
if i call in @aftersuites , the result is displayed after everysuites is executed.

Comment: Try with implementing the ISuiteListener. It has a onFinish() method which might help. https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/ISuiteListener.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Extent Reports (http://extentreports.com/), there are based on test (method/class) wherever You like it, because You set what and where  You want to report, inside Your code, and it doesn't matter how many suites are You running. Really good for step reporting. Check this library and if You like it I can provide additional code to back it up.

Check this example http://klov.herokuapp.com/dashboard